# How to get UV coordinates of data.loop_triangles (Scripting)

Tags: python, scripting

How to get UV coordinates of `mesh.data.loop_triangles` made by `mesh.data.calc_loop_triangles()` per vertex?

Answer (score 1):

UVs are not stored one-per-vertex, they are stored one-per-corner-of-a-face (Blender calls a corner a "loop" internally for some reason). Think of a mesh like this

[image: 2 faces, 4 verts, 6 corners]

There are 2 faces, 4 verts, and 6 corners. Imagine there's a UV seam along the v2-v4 edge. That means the UV at eg. corners c2 and c4 can be different, as shown in the UV map. That would be impossible if there was a single UV pair for v2. Instead there are 6 UV pairs, one for every face corner.

In general, Blender has

- stuff stored per vertex (vertex position, vertex groups, etc.)
- stuff stored per corner (UVs, vertex colors, normals, etc.)
- stuff stored per edge (sharp, UV seam, etc.)
- stuff stored per face (material, smooth shading, etc.)

So if you want to get (pos, norm, uv) triples for a mesh, you need to get one triple *per corner* (not per vertex). You can do it like this

```py
mesh.calc_loop_triangles()

# calculate per-loop normals
# (there are also per-vertex normals but they're
# probably not what you want)
mesh.calc_normals_split()

# array of (pos, norm, uv) triples, three per triangle
vs = []

uvmap = mesh.uv_layers.active

for tri in mesh.loop_triangles:
    for i in range(3):
        vert_index = tri.vertices[i]
        loop_index = tri.loops[i]

        pos = mesh.vertices[vert_index].co
        norm = mesh.loops[loop_index].normal
        uv = uvmap.data[loop_index].uv

        vs.append((pos, norm, uv))
```

Usually you will also want to dedupe identical (pos, norm, uv) triples and use triangle indices, but this is the basic form.

Comment: But I have a renderer that has uses {pos, norm, uv} per vertex. How do I put to vertex? I cannot seem to understand how loop correlates to vertex. Can you point that out, please?
(In short I do not understand how to use that UV)

Comment: You can get the vertex index for a loop with `mesh.loops[loop_index].vertex_index`, but for your renderer, what you usually want to do is export one {pos, norm, uv} triple per Blender loop (not per Blender vertex). As an optimization, you can dedupe identical {pos, norm, uv} values.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still seem to not understand, each vertex must have a UV, but the loop only gives 1 uv(1 vec2) per loop(which is 3 vertices)? What do I do? I am really confused.

Comment: Vertices do not have UVs. I've edited to elaborate this point and show how to get (pos, norm, uv) triples.